# Polymer app-storage and storing an array

Tags: polymer

I want to sync an element with an array property with the local storage by using an app-localstorage-document. What's the best way to do this a the app-localstorage-document supports only objects and not arrays to bind to the data property?

- Should I implement my own app-localstorage-document implementation?
- Can I use another mechanism that wraps the array into an object and back?

for example:

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Local Storage is a key-value database, so you can not store an array without a key in such database. if you want to store your array, you can use a computed property to build the object from your array:

```
objectToStore: {
  type: Object,
  computed: 'computeObject(myArray.splices)'
}
```

And in your compute function generate the object:

```
computeObject: function(){
  return {
    someKey: this.myArray
  }
}
```

And then bind **objectToStore** to your app-localstorage-document element.

Comment: thanks, problem is the app-localstorage-document binding works two-ways (up and down), so the property should not be read-only as it is when binding to a computed property, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seemed to be the storage of an array. I used the app-local-storage in a Polymer test in the setup with a fixture. The setup (also async) doesn't wait until the app-local-storage is completely initialized and this caused some side effects. Adding a call to "getStoredValue(...)" and sync on this call seemed to be a workaround.